# How to generate and validate input text box dynamically when checkbox is selected

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have to handle multiple checkbox in reactive form with selection options as "W9", "F9", "other" and when "other" is selected, then a text box should get open, also required validation is needed for this. When I submit this I should get output as {"Role":{W9:true, other:true,otherValue:value}}

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.customerForm = this.fb.group({

      Roles: this.buildRoles()
    }) 

buildRoles() {
    const arr = this.roles.map(role => {

      return this.fb.control(false);
   });

   console.log(this.fb.array(arr));
   return this.fb.array(arr);
 }

get role() {
    return <FormArray>this.customerForm.get('roles');
  }
```

HTML file

```
  <label>Role</label>

  <div  *ngFor="let control of role.controls; let i = index;">
    <input  type="checkbox"  
    [formControl] = "control">
    <label>{{roles[i]}}</label>
```

I'm just able to get array of true and false based on selection of checkbox without the value of other.

Comment: Please create a StackBlitz showcasing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In .ts file create an array for roles

```
Roles = [
    { id: true, description: 'W9' },
    { id: true', description: 'F9' },
    { id: true, description: 'other' },
  ];
```

function to check and uncheck and logic for displaying another text field when other is checked

```
  updateChkbxArray(chk, isChecked): void {
    const chkArray = <FormArray>this.customerForm.get('Roles');
    if (isChecked) {
      // sometimes inserts values already included creating double records for the same values -hence the defence
      if (chkArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value === chk.id) === -1)
        chkArray.push(new FormControl(chk.id));
    } else {
      const idx = chkArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value === chk.id);
      chkArray.removeAt(idx);
    }
    if (chk.description === 'other') ) {
      // show/hide another textbox
     this.otherValue = true
    }
  }
```

Currently I am showing checkbox in angular material checkbox. You can have your own checkbox.

```
 <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let role of Roles" formArrayName="Roles"
                                (change)="updateChkbxArray(role, $event.checked')"
                                [value]="role.id">{{role.description}}
                  </mat-checkbox>
```